# How to extract the triangles existing in a path of rectangle in a svg file?

Tags: image-processing, svg, dtd, delaunay

I'm working on Delaunay triangulation. I tried this code: https://github.com/esimov/triangle and I wanted to explore the svg file which is the result of the triangulation, but when I have inspected certain elements, I realized that the variable path in the file does not indicate the triangles but the rectangles. How can I profit form this to have the coordinates of the triangles?

This is a part of the code:

```
<path
        fill="rgba(255,254,246,255)"
        stroke="rgba(255,254,246,255)"
        d="M0,0 L2,220 L0,606 L0,0"
    />
    
    <path
        fill="rgba(84,62,54,255)"
        stroke="rgba(84,62,54,255)"
        d="M2342,2611 L2344,2581 L2362,2577 L2342,2611"
    />
    
    <path
        fill="rgba(98,80,74,255)"
        stroke="rgba(98,80,74,255)"
        d="M2388,2546 L2362,2577 L2354,2568 L2388,2546"
    />
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The paths _are_ triangles. Note that the fourth coordinate is identical to the first one. `M0,0 L2,220 L0,606 L0,0` is identical when rendered to `M0,0 L2,220 L0,606 L0,0 Z` and to `M0,0 L2,220 L0,606 Z`. (with the exception of the rendering of a stroke join on the first point)

Comment: Alright, i just got it from you, i didn't remarks that the last point is the same to the first, thank you very much, that's help.